# how to get rid of pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing the following operation with `pandas`:

I select a subset of the data frame

```
data_for_model = data[['dt', 'y']]
```

and then I do the following:

```
data_for_model['y'] = data_for_model['y'].apply(lambda x: x / 60.0)
```

Here I hit the warning:

```
 SettingWithCopyWarning: 
 A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
 Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So, I am not sure how to fix it in this case. I tried this:

```
data_for_model.loc[:, 'y'] = data_for_model.loc[:, 'y'].apply(lambda x: x / 60.0)
```

However, the warning persists.

Comment: Use `data_for_model = data[['dt', 'y']].copy()`

Comment: You can also first do `apply`  and after this select subset of dataframe, if there are no additional requirements.